# google <button> <a> on Internet Explorer issue

Tags: internet-explorer, button

I am trying to use Google's buttons code with styling and for some reason I am having problems in IE. It just does not work on IE, the style does and the button looks great, however, when you click it, nothing happens....

Any help would be great

I tried adding button="type" and that did not help...

CSS:

```
button.g-button.large {
    padding: 12px 20px; font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; 
   }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="sample.html"><button class="g-button large">Search</button></a>
```

Comment: To be more specific, I found these buttons http://www.zurb.com/playground/google-buttons and they don't work in explorer... not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on Safari, it should work:

```
<a href="link.html"><input type="button" value="Search" /></a>
```

If not, try using JavaScript:

```
function foo(){
    window.open("link.html");
}
```

and:

```
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="foo()" />
```

Edit: From the comments on another answer, it would appear you don't know JavaScript. To use the above code, place it inside of `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` in the `<head>` of your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks, would that preserve the Google webkit styling?

Comment: @user1110834 The CSS present in your question?

Comment: it wont work with the A tag for some reason... if I add a class to it.

Comment: @user1110834 You are adding `class="g-button large"` and it's not working?

Comment: <input type="button" value="search" onclick="foo()" class="g-button large/>Search For Free

Comment: @user1110834 Well, you need to close the quotation marks after `large`.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Search For Free" onclick="foo()" class="g-button large"/>

Comment: And make sure there's a space between them like so: `"g-button large" />`

Comment: Oh! It's because your CSS thinks it's a button; change it to `input.g-button.large`

Comment: Thank You! Its working!... one more Javascript related question

Comment: what do I have to change here so that the window opened is the same window and not a new window? window.open("sample.html");

Comment: @user1110834 If it's working, could you accept? :-) And use `window.navigate` instead of `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the javascript event "onClick" on the button element?

Comment: Nope, I don't know Javascript :(

Comment: @user1110834 My answer contains JavaScript, and a short intro to using it.